# filter data from complex values in magento grid

Tags: magento, filter, grid, render, complex-data-types

Hi I have added a new column in a shipment grid as below

```
    $this->addColumn('telephone', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Phone'),
    'index' => 'telephone',

    'renderer'=> new OSP_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Renderer_BillingPhone()
    ));
```

in this i am using a renderer to show custom values as below

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
        $customer_id = $row->getData('customer_id');

    if( $customer_id > 0 ) {
        // get member_id (club canon)
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
        if( is_object( $customer ) ) {
            $value = $customer->getData('mobile');
        }
    }else{
    $id = $row->getData('order_increment_id');
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id);
    $value = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
}
    return $value;
}
```

> which is working fine and it shows data properly on the basis of
>   condition in renderer.
>
> But the problem is now I need to filter the data also which is not
>   working as it looks for data in only one column as telephone or mobile
>   I have read about  `filter_condition_callback` but unable to make the work . Can you please suggest me how can I make this work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1.Add line `filter_condition_callback` to column, like that:

```
 $this->addColumn('telephone', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Phone'),
    'index' => 'telephone',
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_someCallBackFunction'),
    'renderer'=> new OSP_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Renderer_BillingPhone()
    ));
```

After you added this line in your column, Magento  will call this callback function, look `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php` in 468 line.

2.In your block grid file create `_someCallBackFunction` function, which will take two parameters, `$collection` - collection object not loaded, and `$column` `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column`

```
protected function _someCallBackFunction($collection, $column)
{
    $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
    if ($value === null) { //here check if filter is not null
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Here you can add filter to collection
     * or do other manipulations with collection.
     * As example you can check filter value and filter collection.
     */
    if ($value != 0) { 
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('telephone', array('neq' => 0));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Look threw steps in my answer.

Comment: i mean in call back function , i am unable to add filter there in collection Can you help me in that.thanks

Comment: Added example how to add filter to collection in callback function

Comment: can you also help me in joining table  as i need          $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id); as you can see in my renderer

Comment: it means if it founds customer id than it should show mobile else it should fetch telephone in search